# Получение статуса пользователя ВК через API

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Искал общие методы api vk для получения статуса пользователя, так ничего и не нашёл.
Подскажите каким методом можно получить статус пользователя без авторизации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только парсить страницу.
Для работы с API нужен Access Token + приложение должно быть зарегистрировано ВКонтакте.

Answer (score 0):

[Вот, почитайте](http://lifeexample.ru/php-primeryi-skriptov/kak-rabotat-s-vk-api-vkontakte.html)

Answer (score 0):

1) Получаешь токен

2) Дергаешь метод status.get

Если нужно будет, объясню подробнее

Comment: Так ему же, вроде, без авторизации нужно.

Comment: Ну тогда я бессилен